# Swift - refactoring common code to a protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have multiple classes that have code that calls a common network class to make a GET api call.  Below is an example of one:

```
public typealias Api1Result = (Result<Api1Model>) -> Void

private var path = "the/path/api1"

public enum Api1ServiceError: String, Error {
    case error = "Sorry, the api1 service returned something different than expected"
}

extension Api1Model {

    public static func getApi1(networkClient: NetworkClient = networkClient, completion: @escaping Api1Result) {
        networkClient.getPath(path) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let api1Model = try JSONDecoder().decode(Api1Model.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(api1Model))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(Api1ServiceError.error))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Here is the Result enum if interested:

```
public enum Result<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

There are several other model classes, and the only difference is the actual model class being decoded (`Api1Model` in this case), as well as the completion typealias (`Api1Result`).  It does the exact same thing across several others, just makes the call to the `networkClient.getPath()` method, checks for success/failure, and calls the completion closure.

Curious if there are any protocol experts out there who could assist in simplifying this and refactoring so I don't have the same boiler-plate code across multiple classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a protocol extension (untested)

```
protocol ApiModel {
    associatedtype ApiType : Decodable = Self

    static var path : String { get }
    static func getApi1(networkClient: NetworkClient, completion: @escaping (Result<ApiType>) -> Void)

}

extension ApiModel where Self : Decodable {   
    static func getApi1(networkClient: NetworkClient, completion: @escaping (Result<ApiType>) -> Void) {
        networkClient.getPath(path) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let api1Model = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiType.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(api1Model))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(Api1ServiceError.error))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make all your classes conform to `ApiModel` and add the static `path` property. The type alias is going to be inferred.

Comment: Thank you for this!  It's the kind of solution I was looking for.  However, when implementing, some compile errors were thrown, specifically around the references to "Result<ApiType>".  It complained about "@escaping" only applies to function types, and on the lines that call the completion closure, it gives me "cannot call value of non-function type Result<Self.ApiType>".  It now doesn't seem to be recognizing the call when in this context.  Thoughts?  I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: It depends on the context. It's unclear how the static method is called.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  What other info would be helpful to clarify this?  When using the existing code, to make the actual call, we would simply just code: "Api1Model.getApi1 { (result) in...."  Before hand, we had the typealias which was an actual closure, so I can see why this error is being thrown (now it's just a return result enum/structure).

Comment: Looks like it fixes it when I change the completion obj to this instead: "(Result<ModelType>) -> Void"

Comment: Oh no worries, I've updated the solution.  Thank you again very much!  You have been more than helpful.